# Watch output of MySQL query over time

Tags: mysql

I'd like to run a query every few seconds and show the output in a console window.  From bash, using `watch`:

```
watch "mysql -A -pXXXXX -h host -D dbname -u username --vertical -e \"SELECT rowID FROM IDs LIMIT 1\""
```

With the output:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
rowID: 68434810
```

I'd like to not disconnect and reconnect every 2 seconds though.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Just to let me understand, why do you want to persist a connection to MySQL to do it?

Comment: That's what I'm looking for, yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a cheap/low-tech way of doing this:

```sh
while [ 1 ] ; do echo "select rowid from ids limit 1;" ; sleep 2; done \
 | mysql -u ...
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> to interrupt.

Comment: Nice, it worked here! +1

Comment: Very nice, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: (BTW that select is suspicious. Unless `IDs` always has a single row (in which case the limit clause is redundant) or you need an `order by` for the result to be meaningful.)